# How do you determine the electromotive force when the negative plate of the capacitor is connected to the positive terminal?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$We have a square wave source with period $T$ and voltage $V_0$ connected to a circuit which is has a resistor of resistance $R$ in series with an uncharged capacitor of capacitance $C$. I want to determine the long term steady state of the voltage across the capacitor's plates, I was told it is supposed to alternate between $\pm V_\max$ for some $V_\max$ to be determined. All units are the standard SI units. To be clear, the square wave source supplies $+V_0$ for the first $T/2$ seconds, then $-V_0$ for the interval $[T/2,T]$, then $+V_0$ for $[T,3T/2]$, etc.

I decided to go back to basics first, by going through the well known formula $V=V_0(1-\exp(-t/RC))$ for the voltage across the plates of the capacitor after time $t$ when charged under a constant voltage $V_0$. The way I like to think about this formula:

> Electrons on the plate of the capacitor connected to the positive terminal of the source will be attracted to said terminal and "move away", leaving that plate positive. Similarly, electrons on the negative terminal will "move away" and accumulate on the plate connected said terminal. This is a current: if $Q$ is the charge stored on the capacitor, then $\frac{\d Q}{\d t}$ should equal $V'/R$ where $V'$ is the net potential that is accelerating electrons from the negative terminal to the (negative) plate. When the capacitor has a potential difference $V$ across its plates, this difference is acting against the source because positive repels positive, negative repels negative, so this effective voltage $V'$ is $V_0-V$ and we have: $$\frac{\d Q}{\d t}=\frac{V_0-V}{R}=\frac{V_0}{R}-\frac{Q}{RC}$$And solving this ODE with initial condition $Q(0)=0$ finds: $$Q(t)=V_0C(1-\exp(-t/RC))$$Hence: $$V(t)=V_0(1-\exp(-t/RC))$$

I want to apply this kind of thinking to the problem at hand.

Now, after the first $T/2$ seconds we have, by this formula, a potential difference of $V_0(1-\exp(-T/2RC))$ across the plates of the capacitor. But then, the source flips polarity and we have the below diagram:

[image: Circuit]

Now the positive terminal of the source will attract the electrons from the negative plate of the capacitor, and that attraction is counteracted by the potential difference on the capacitor since the positive charges on the other plate "want to keep the electrons there", as in the above computation. So there is a $V_0-V$ net potential difference that makes the negative plate lose electrons. But the source voltage makes the electrons flow out of the negative terminal and want to accumulate on the positive plate, but the electrons on the negative plate are going to resist this, right? But it's confusing, because the positivity of the positive plate is going to attract those electrons, which is helping the source rather than counteracting it.
**I have no idea how to decide the net electromotive force here**, so I tried "both" possibilities: $$-\frac{\d Q}{\d t}=\frac{V_0+V}{R},\,\text{ or }\,-\frac{\d Q}{\d t}=\frac{V_0-V}{R}$$Solving these ODEs subject to $Q(0)=VC$ for some given initial potential difference $V$ (which will be $V_0(1-\exp(-T/2RC))$ at first, but generality is useful) and converting $Q$ into $V$ we have *either* (after the $T/2$ length of this section of the square wave): $$V_{\text{final}}=V_0+(V_{\text{initial}}-V_0)\exp(-T/2RC)$$Or: $$V_{\text{final}}=V_0+(V_{\text{initial}}-V_0)\exp(T/2RC)$$Specialising $V_{\text{initial}}=V_0(1-\exp(-T/2RC))$ in these equations tells me that, after one full cycle of the square wave, the voltage across the plates is: $$V_0(1-\exp(-T/RC))\quad\text{ or }\quad 0$$

"$0$" is quite likely wrong, so I infer that the modelling assumption of $-\frac{\d Q}{\d t}=\frac{V_0-V}{R}$ is wrong, i.e. the idea that the potential difference across the capacitor plates is resisting the action of the source is wrong. But the idea that the positive plate wants to retain the electrons on the negative plate is quite appealing, so I'm not sure what makes it wrong. But now I have a new problem: the alternative value $V=V_0(1-\exp(-T/RC))$ is going to be positive relative to the initial "positive" orientation at $t=0$. But the voltage across the plates should have reversed direction after the negative part of the square wave - according to the source of the question - so the model $-\frac{\d Q}{\d t}=\frac{V_0+V}{R}$ is *also* wrong, somehow.

What's the right way to think about, and decide a value of, the emf here, when I'm trying to setup the ODE? What *concepts* should I have in mind (or correct my understanding of) to help me realise why both of my models were wrong?

Comment: Just a remark: The period $T$ is meaningless as long as you don't know how it's related to $\tau = R \cdot C$. In other words: it depends on how many time the capacitor has to charge or discharge during $T/2$, like "no time at all" ($\Delta V \approx 0$ or "close to infinity" ($\Delta V \approx 2 \cdot V_{max}$.

Comment: @MS-SPO I should expect to answer the question for any precise value of the ratio $T/RC$, be it small, huge, or otherwise

Comment: Hm, how does that fit with the expected limes? "The task is to determine the long term steady state of the voltage across the capacitor's plates"

Comment: @MS-SPO Yeah, i.e. find the "eventual" values of $V_\max$. Precisely you could say that we care about $\limsup_{t\to\infty}V$ and $\liminf_{t\to\infty}V$ Sure, we could work in relative units of $T/RC=1$, but I want to keep things SI so it's a simple matter of plugging in values when the formula is ready

Comment: Have you already studied Fourier series and/or Laplace transforms? Specifically, can you calculate the Fourier series of the source voltage, or just look it up in a book?

Comment: @hyportnex In the mathematical sense, sort of, but I'd like to hope this problem can be handled without them (it's targeted at good A level students, who in theory know nothing like Laplace transforms)

Comment: Don't know what A level is but forget "Laplace". Expand the input source sequence  into its Fourier series (or just look it up), each term is a sinusoid that can independently excite your RC circuit. Calculate the voltage drop on the capacitor for each  term, then sum them. The result is another Fourier series that you can easily evaluate numerically, just take no more than 8 terms, or so.

Comment: @hyportnex "A level" is the final little bit of UK high school. So, I know this can be done in closed form with more elementary techniques. Regardless, I'm not very experienced in mathematical physics. I can make series computations but I really don't have any idea how to realise your hint.